# can we add <lightning:tab> dynamically in the component

Tags: lightning, tab

I have added a

```
<lightning:tab>
```

in a lightning component. On button click I want to add this new tab.

Is there any way to do this. Please suggest.

Comment: corrected typo: I have added a tab in a lightning component using <lightning:tab>

Comment: I think so that you can add a tab dynamically using `$A.createComponent Method` however dynamically generated components tend to give errors in future specially while firing and capturing events. If you want to dynamically add/ remove tab you can either show or hide them or use [LDS tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#flavor-scoped).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your complete usecase but you can use aura:iteration to create new tabs.

```
<aura:attribute name="v.tabList" type="List"/>
<lightning:tabset aura:id="tabset" >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.tabList}" var="item">
           <lightning:tab id="{!item.id>>
           </lightning:tab>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:tabset>
```

and you can dynamically add and remove items from tabList to add or remove tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $A.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, function callback) method.

If you have a button in your component, let it call a method that implements the following code:

```
$A.createComponent(
            "lightning:tab",
            {
                "title": "Your dynamic Tab" //you can add more variables here
            },
            function(newTab, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new tab to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newTab);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                }
            }
        );
```

You also need to add `{!v.body}` expression to your component where you want your tab.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: This do not work as we cannot set the body on a tab. Trying to set body on tab will cause an exception. Instead look at the example provided in docs. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm